# Quit application after last window closes

Tags: cocoa, macos, nswindow, nsapplication

I want to close my application when the last main window closes. I cannot use `applicationShouldTerminateAfterLastWindowClosed:` for the following reasons:
1. Before showing the main window, one confirmation window is displayed and when this window is closed, the application should not quit.
2. The application should quit after closing the main window even if there is any help window still open.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you need to do is set you controlling class as the delegate of your main window, and then using NSNotificationCenter add an observer with the NSWindowWillCloseNotification with yourWindow being the object. So like this

```
NSNotificationCenter *c = [NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter];
[c addObserver:self selector:@selector(yourSelector) name:NSWindowWillCloseNotification object:yourWindow];
```

Now, the method yourSelector will be called when the main window is close, so in that method just have something like exit(0);

For more info go [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/cocoa/reference/NSWindowDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html) and look at windowWillClose

Comment: I guess `[NSApp terminate:self];` is better than `exit(0);.`

Comment: Yes, that would be, I was just giving a rough example.

Answer (score 14):

You may still use `applicationShouldTerminateAfterLastWindowClosed:`

Write it to return `NO` until the moment you first show the main window. Make it return `YES` from then onwards.

Instances of NSPanel don't count towards open windows. Thus this will work if your help window is a NSPanel.

Comment: This could be one solution using notification was simpler to me.